# Overscan fixing in X11 or XFCE or Gnome natively without xrandr

Tags: x11, gnome, xfce

I have a TV monitor with overscan and no way to turn it off.

I have tried xrandr based solutions, but they are either not supported by my graphic card driver or they involve transformation that makes the picture blurry due to the pixel interpolation.

I would like to ask if you know of any window environment such as XFCE or Gnome that supports overscan fixing natively without xrandr transformations. I just want a window manager in which I can specify the rectangle on my physical monitor to which all the widgets will be mapped. That should not be too complex as it needs to store this rectangle somewhere anyway.

Or is it possible to solve this on the level of X11? Preferably I would like to do it using configuration file but the functionality is so important to me that if I have to compile the environment with this functionality I would do it.

Please do not send any solutions involving xrandr or changing/configuring screen.

Thanks.

Comment: A developer of Gnome, whom I have asked for help as he was involved in similar function implementation pointed out this https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1046
Here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1046 is mentioned the functionality but no direct mention on how its implemented or configured, code in the commit https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2015-April/msg05872.html.

Answer (score 1):

I too have one of those TVs.

LXDE (lubuntu up to 18.04) and LXQT (lubuntu 19.04 and above) use the openbox window manager and it allows you to set margins.

Go to preferences, openbox, margins and fiddle with the numbers. It's not a perfect solution (doesn't affect full-screen or the panel) but it helps.